# Find a user input key on a map

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a map variable and I'm trying to use the "find" function to discover if something is in that map. That something is a string the user inputs.
If I do like the code I posted below, "it" (iterator) always fails, even if the "typedRoadName" exists in the map variable.

But for example, if I write "John's Road" instead of using the input variable, the iterator finds it, but if I use the variable, even if I write the same, it fails.

Any idea why?

```
string typedRoadName;
map<string, int> roadInfo;
vector<string> roadNames;

StringAlgorithms *algorithm = new StringAlgorithms();
gps->getRoadNames(roadInfo);
//roadInfo is filled using the line above

map<string, int>::iterator it;
for (it = roadInfo.begin(); it != roadInfo.end(); it++)
    roadNames.push_back(it->first);

cout << "\nType the desired road name:\n>>";
cin >> typedRoadName;

it = roadInfo.find(typedRoadName);
//it = roadInfo.find("John's Road"); --> it works!

if (it == roadInfo.end())
    cout << "Failed!\n";
else {
    gps->setsourceID(it->second);
    cout << "You've set the origin to '" << it->first << "' road, node --> " << it->second << endl;
}
```

Comment: BTW `cin >> typedRoadName;` will stop reading at spaces. so instead of `John's Road` it will only read `John's`. you probably need `getline(cin,typedRoadName)` there.

Comment: Your typedRoadName will only contain John's , Debug that , you will see what value is it finding in map.

Comment: Before doing getline() , clear the cin for any left over characters like '\n'

Comment: OMG that did the trick! Thank you guys very much!